# how to program in C with lib gtk in vim with coc-clangd?

Tags: vim, clang, clang++, coc.nvim, clangd

I copied the ["Hello world" code from the website of the GTK project](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html) and pasted it into Vim with the environment to develop in C properly configured with [coc-clangd](https://github.com/clangd/coc-clangd). However, several errors are shown in the

`#include <gtk/gtk.h>`

But when I send compile with the command:

`` gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o hello-world-gtk hello-world-gtk.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` ``

it works perfectly
I tried to add

`` `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` ``

in

`clangd.fallbackFlags`

in `:CocConfig` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting.html

https://sarcasm.github.io/notes/dev/compilation-database.html

`` clang -MJ hello-world-gtk.o.json `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o hello-world-gtk hello-world-gtk.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` ``

`sed -e '1s/^/[\n/' -e '$s/,$/\n]/' *.o.json > compile_commands.json`